# Where is unsigned int defined for embedded systems?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, bare-metal

Using the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` toolchain.

During ARM development using options `-nostdlib` in the linker,i can use unsigned int, int etc.
However for `uint8_t` i have to use  `--specs=nano.specs`, since they are in the newlib standard library.

So how is `unsigned int` being resolved?

i have been doing ARM development for quite some time using an IDE. Hence didnt know how the underlying stuff works.
Was going through some bare metal tutorial when i encountered these doubts.

Thank you.

Comment: `However for uint8_t i have to use --specs=nano.specs, since they are in the newlib standard library.` That's close to unrelated. `nano.specs` links with a small version of newlib library (for example, `%lld` in `printf` doesn't work). You can link with full version, you can just `#include <stdint.h>` the file only or even do `typedef __UINT8_TYPE__ uint8_t` in your code (see ex. `arm-none-eabi-gcc -dM -E - </dev/null | grep -i uint8`).

Comment: the compiler authors choose the size of int, long, short, char as those are basic variable types.  THEN they have to make stdint.h to match the sizes advertised, uint32_t for example.  There is no expectation that two different compilers (or versions of) for the same target have the same definitions.  so either check the sizes for your compiler or use stdint.h (and check the sizes)

Comment: I hope you dont mean uint8_t is DEFINED in the newlib library, that would be a bug.  Only the compiler author knows, it is a compiler supplied header not a library supplied header...unless...the library points at or makes a copy of or otherwise uses the compiler supplied header.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`unsigned int` is a basic type defined by the C standard (see C99 §6.2.5, page 33 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)), it isn't defined anywhere else, the compiler already knows how to handle it.

`uint8_t` and other similar types are implementation defined and therefore you may find those defined in library headers.

Comment: Thank you. Is it recommended or standard practice to use the stdlibs or newlib in one's project. i dont intend to use memory alloc, printf statements. is there any particular overhead involved with the libraries?

Comment: @Hemant not sure what you are asking, but you usually cannot use stdlib at all, so if you ever need any library function and you don't want to implement the function yourself, you need to use newlib or something similar. Of course using complex functions *can* result in a performance overhead, but it really all depends on the specific case, it's impossible to say beforehand.

Comment: @Hemant `<stdint.h>` is simply a header file with no associated object code, you can most probably use the header without linking the whole library since it does not declare anything that is defined in the library. Linking the standard library will only link those parts of it that you actually use.  There may be a library initialisation step in your C runtime startup (code that runs before main) so a small overhead perhaps.  Much of the library will work correctly without such initialisation; it primarily relates to stdio and heap management, so you could modify or omit it.

Comment: @Hemant standard libraries including newlib have a lot of system calls, bare metal means no system so you have to patch in the system if you want to use them and yes there is a lot of overhead.   newlib is somewhat designed for this as there is one file/place where you patch in your system solution and you only need to patch in what you are using, no alloc then just return pass on the related funcitons, I tend to make them all just return success, then fill in what I need.

Comment: As silly as it sounds (but it happens) if you want to use stdint.h then make sure you have the right one, set up your build or system wrong and you might be trying to target say an ARM microcontroller with stdint.h definitions based on the x86-64 host you are doing the development on...plant some if sizeof this is not that here and there as a check.  I would argue any time you use stdint.h...but...YMMV

Comment: @old_timer regrading using the proper `stdint.h` .. yes the IDE is using the one that comes bundled with the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` package. However if i use `unsigned char`, shouldnt the arm-gcc compiler manage the size automatically for me?

Comment: @old_timer with respect to system call the IDE attached a `syscalls.h`and `memcall.h` which i understand ill have to implement to have printf and malloc functionality.

Comment: @old_timer  the IDE startup file was using '__libc_init_array' to initialize the stdlib or newlib (i dont which is the right term to use here. does newlib have stdlib and a number of system calls?) is what i understood for searching the net. so if use `-nostdlib` i should be OK  removing  '__libc_init_array'. I was studying your github repo for bare metal examples. Thank you